# outoput echo in php in body is # and not link

Tags: php, html, database, url, echo

Today I found a very weird problem on my php page. I would like to insert a link by php echo instruction a link in href tag, but when I load the page the link is "#".

code of www.siteexemple.com/page.php

```
<head>
     echo $web_link['UrlFromDB']; 
     // shows correct URL (www.siteexemple.com/page2.php)
</head>

<body>
    <li><a href="http://www.siteexemple.com/page2.php">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $web_link['UrlFromDB']; ?>" > link2 </a></li>
// shows (www.siteexemple.com/page.php/#) 

    echo $web_link['UrlFromDB']; // shows (www.siteexemple.com/page.php/#) 
</body>
```

I tried to print the $web_link['UrlFromDB'] and if the echo is on the body the link will be # but if you print by echo before the body it shows the right link.

someone can help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you see the `#` if you use `View Source`?

Comment: You should do a `var_dump()` of your variable to see what it contains exactly.

Comment: i tried the same code on my local and it work for me no issue with this code.
please clear your cache once then try this again

Comment: On the header file included the my variable was re-writed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that somewhere between copying/pasting your HTML from your computer to here you have accidentally fixed/hidden an HTML error in the A tag.

If the HREF property tag is missing or not closed correctly some browsers can't understand it. In most browsers, the default URL for any link without a valid HREF property is to append "#" to the end of the current URL.

The HTML error might not even be on the A tag but could be in a previous tag on the same page. You are most probably a missing closing quote somewhere.

Comment: thank you so much. also your answer was very helpful.